# How do you trigger the next record in the PHP array via the HTML submit button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

**Goal:** I want to create an HTML form that displays pre-populated information from the 22 arrays from array_file.php.

First, I will go on index.php. On index.php, I will see a form with pre-populated data. I will not be able to edit the first and last name fields, but I will be able to edit the email field (if necessary).

Second, once everything looks okay, I will click the "Submit" button.

Third, if nothing is wrong (i.e., email field is populated), the "Submit" button should take me to the second record in the array.

Finally, once it has looped through all the arrays, it will provide a message, such as, "You're done!"

**Current problem:** My current index.php page shows all 22 pre-populated forms on one page. While I can edit and submit to the database using the individual "Submit" button, I'd rather be able to look at each pre-populated form one at a time.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

ob_start();
include 'array_file.php';
ob_end_clean();
?>

 <?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=22){
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">

<h2>Form</h2>
<label>First Name:</label>
<input class="input" name="first_name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($array[$i][1]) ?>" disabled><br>
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input class="input" name="last_name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($array[$i][2]) ?>" disabled><br>
<label>Email:</label>
<input class="input" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($array[$i][3]) ?>"><br><br>
<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
   $i=$i+1;
     }

?>


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    if($email !=''){


  //Insert Query of SQL
    mysqli_query(#conn,"INSERT into form(form_first_name, form_last_name, form_email) values ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')");
    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data inserted successfully!</span>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some required fields are blank!</p>";
    }
    }
    $mysqli->close(); // Closing Connection with Server
    ?>
```

Let me know if you need me to provide any more information. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is **no more support** for ``mysql_*`` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in PHP 7.0.0. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Not only functionality, but security as well.  This code is **wide open** to MySQL injection attacks, and has likely already been hijacked by an automated bot.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out for me. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Do you want to send 22 form by clicking one submit button,  right ?

Comment: @Fatihd I would like to submit one pre-populated form, click submit, then move on to the next pre-populated form.

Comment: Use JS to modify the user's window and `fetch` data back and forth between the user and the server. You can pull previous answers, and send new answers along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code is what you need.

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   include 'array_file.php';
   ob_end_clean();

if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_POST[email])){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    if($email !=''){

  //Insert Query of SQL
    mysqli_query(#conn,"INSERT into form(form_first_name, form_last_name, form_email) values ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')");
    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data inserted successfully!</span>";

}

}


/// find which form will be published
if( isset($_SESSION["form"]) and $_SESSION["form"]<22){
     $form=$_SESSION["form"]+1;
    $_SESSION["form"]=$form;
}else{
    $form=1; 
    $_SESSION["form"]=$form;
}

// determine which is the next form number
if($form<22){ $nextForm=$form+1; }else{ $nextForm="??";  }


<!-- form area  !-->
<form action="index.php?form=<?php echo $nextForm; ?>" method="post">

<h2>Form</h2>
<label>First Name:</label>
<input class="input" name="first_name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($array[$form][1]) ?>" disabled><br>
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input class="input" name="last_name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($array[$form][2]) ?>" disabled><br>
<label>Email:</label>
<input class="input" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($array[$form][3]) ?>"><br><br>
<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Where/how do I insert the code before the form area?

Comment: I replaced   $i=$i+1; } with it and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I got it to work. The edited code is below: `<?php

if(isset($_GET["form"]) and is_numeric($_GET["form"])){
    $form=htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET["form"]));
}else{
    $form=1;
}

// determine which is the next form number
if($form<22){ $nextForm=$form+1;
}
else{
 echo "<p>You're done!</p>";
}

?>


<form action="index.php?form=<?php echo $nextForm; ?>" method="post">`

Comment: Is it possible to not always start from 1 but start from where I (or some other user) last left off? And prevent duplicate entires? (For example, if I've already submitted record 1, I should not be allowed to submit it again.)

Comment: i edited my answer and put full code . and if you put `action="index.php?form=<?php echo $nextForm; ?"` in form action , automatically goes next form.

Comment: Thanks @Fatihd, but I think the code you posted yesterday (which I modified) is closer to what I was looking for. I was wondering if it's possible for people to navigate to another website at around, say, the third form, then return to see the fourth form?